# How to make emacs to start allwais --nw if I launch it from command line?

Tags: bash, emacs

How to make Emacs to start always `--nw` if I launch it from command line?
I have such export in my `.profile`:

```
alias emacs='emacs -nw'
```

when I type `emacs` alone it will launch it in terminal in terminal mode, but when i type `emacs filename.fn` it will create separate frame in graphical mode. I want it to launch in terminal when ever I I use my terminal.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. What does `type emacs` say when the alias is not defined?

Comment: I think I found the solution  - I should put `export` before alias...